# Click event on a link with a unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

On a page I have links, by clicking them, it deletes an element. This is my code:

```
<a href="#" class="remove-existed-field" id="link0">Delete input</a>
<a href="#" class="remove-existed-field" id="link1">Delete input</a>
```

and so on. As you can see, the links differs with ids, so there can be hundreds links with unique ids. I need to remove closest `li` element to them. I do it in a such way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#link0').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
  })

});
```

It works for `id="link0"`

I tried to put a numerical part of id into a variable `i` by doing this:

```
var i = 0;

$('#link0' + i).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
  })
```

but I can't figure, how to make it work and how should I increment `i`(where should I put in the code `i++`). Any help would be appriciate. Thanks!

Comment: how li is related to links? each li has unique id as of link?

Comment: Why can't you just bind the event listener to the `class` instead of the `id`?

Comment: If i bind it to class, it will delete all closest li's, but not the one I need

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi Could you include the `li` elements into your question so we know how they're structured.

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi No it won't delete all of them since you are using `$(this)` and `closest`. That will only affect 1 element.

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi Here's the documentation for `closest`. https://api.jquery.com/closest/ *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*

Comment: That's strange, cause I tried to bind click event to class, and it didn't work. But for now it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `classes` instead of ids...

You can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.remove-existed-field').on('click', function(e) {
     $(this).closest('li').remove();
   })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" class="remove-existed-field" id="link0">Delete input</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="remove-existed-field" id="link1">Delete input</a></li>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the starts with selector.

```
$('[id^=link]').click(
```

It will target all the elements whose `id` start with `link`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process each link `a` then you could do it on `class` instead.
Also you can get `id` of the clicked link if you really need it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('a.remove-existed-field').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
  });

});
```

Comment: I think this code has already been answered... Its the duplicate of that!